# Why I can not set REST's state up?

Tags: rest, https, solace

[image: image1]

I want set REST's operational State up, so that I can connect solace by solClienetJs. Now I can not connect by "http" or "https". I have enable the REST by solAdmin, but it does not work.

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solace REST service must be enabled on both a system level and a Message VPN level. It looks like you have enabled the incoming REST services for a Message VPN but not on the system-level.

To enable the REST service on the system-level in SolAdmin, navigate to the 'General' tab. On the 'Basic Appliance Properties' view, select 'Configure Service Admin State' from the drop-down menu in the Service Properties section. Select the gear to open a pop-up menu. In the pop-up menu, you can globally enable the incoming REST service and/or the outgoing REST service and press OK. When it is globally enabled, the Operational Status should show as 'Up'.